# How can I obtain the bounding box of an object to separate it from the background

Tags: matlab

I have several images of envelopes.

Some of them are rotated, so I want to find their bounding box to first of all extract them from the background, and then rotate them so their upright.

Everytime I do it I never get the bounding box of the envelope itself, only of the written letters inside and some garbage.

Here is the original picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7X6a.jpg

Here are my results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRe3e.jpg

And here is the code that I used:

```
close all

I=imread('cartatorta.jpg');
BW = edge(rgb2gray(I), 'canny');

st = regionprops(BW, 'BoundingBox' );

figure, imshow(I)

for k = 1 : length(st)
  thisBB = st(k).BoundingBox;
  rectangle('Position', [thisBB(1),thisBB(2),thisBB(3),thisBB(4)],...
  'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 )
end
```

Comment: Again, please make some effort and search for duplicates before posting your question.  It minimizes clutter.

Comment: I did. None of the answers I found helped me.

Comment: Well the one I linked will.  It uses the `regionprops` bounding boxes to find one final bounding box that encapsulates all of them together, which is what you're after.  Good luck.

Comment: The thing about using that is that I have an extra bounding box in the edge of the image, including the background...

Comment: Use `imclearborder` then try again.